# Is there a way to offer multiple video qualities (resolutions) without uploading multiple videos in HTML5 video player?

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to add a few videos to my website using HTML5. My videos are all 1080, but I want to give people the option to watch in a lower quality if needed. Can I do this without having to upload multiple videos (1 for each quality) without the usage of a server-side language?

I've been extensively searching for this. Haven't find anyone say that it can't be done, but no one said it can either. I am using Blogger as my host, which is why I am can't use server-side languages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> without the usage of a server-side language?

Yes, of course.  The client can choose what version of the video to download.

> Can I do this without having to upload multiple videos (1 for each quality)

Not practically, no.  You need to transcode that video and upload those different versions.

> Haven't find anyone say that it can't be done

A couple things to consider... first is that a video file can contain many streams.  I don't know what your aversion is to multiple files, but yes it is possible to have several bitrates of video in a single container.  A single MP4, for example, could easily contain a 768 kbps video, a 2 Mbps video, and an 8 Mbps video, while having a single 256 kbps audio track.

To play such a file, a client (implemented with Media Source Extensions and the Fetch API) would need to know how to parse the container and make ranged requests for specific chunks out of the file.  To my knowledge, no such client exists as there's little point to it when you can simply use DASH and/or HLS.  The browser certainly doesn't do this work for you.

Some video codecs, like H.264, support the concept of scaling.  The idea here is that rather than having multiple encodings, there's just one where additional data enhances the previous video that was sent.  There is significant overhead with this mechanism, and even more work you'd have to do.  Not only does your code now need to understand the container, but now it has to handle the codec in use as well... and it needs to do it efficiently.

To summarize, is it possible to use one file?  Technically, yes.  Is there any benefit?  None.  Is there anything off-the-shelf for this?  No.

**Edit:** I see now your comment that the issue is one of storage space.  You should really put that information in your question so you can get a useful answer.

It's common for YouTube and others to transcode things ahead of time.  This is particularly useful for videos that get a ton of traffic, as the segments can be stored on the CDN, with nodes closer to the clients.  Yes, it's also possible to transcode on-demand as well.  You need fast hardware for this.

Answer (score 0):

No.

I can't fathom how this could ever be possible. Do you have an angle in mind?

Clients can either download all or part(s) of a file. But to do this you would have to somehow download only select pixels of each frame. Even if you had knowledge of which byte-ranges of each frame were which pixels, the overhead involved in requesting each byte-range would be greater than the size of the full 1080p video.

What is your aversion to hosting multiple qualities? Is it about storage space, or complexity/time of conversion?

Comment: It is mostly a problem of storage space. Lets suppose I can use server side languages, would it be possible? Like when you upload a video to youtube, you upload 1 video, and youtube does the rest. Do they convert the video to different qualities and save those on the server? Or do they convert the video in realtime?

Comment: Youtube converts upfront and stores the multiple qualities. You can transcode on the fly, but the server CPU usage will cost you more than storage. If you have 600MB of 1080p video, storing 480p+240p options alongside will add approx 50% (300MB). Where are you storing? S3? And how much are you storing? If you want to encode on your computer before uploading, use ffmpeg. If you want to encode on a server, use ffmpeg + a wrapper in your language of choice (e.g., nodejs fluent-ffmpeg package)

Comment: Or use a cloud transcoder e.g., https://aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/. You can set an AWS Lambda function on an S3 trigger to convert your videos as soon as the original is uploaded to S3. Though if storage is too expensive, this will be even more so